Unable to Alert Address Bar Value in Error State with Chrome Extension
I'm unable to get the current value inside the browser address bar when the page is in an error state, but I don't care if it's in an error state. The fact that there is a value in the address bar should suffice, or am I wrong? I just want to alert what's inside the address bar. In this example, you can see it's in an error state, but there is still a value in the address bar. I just want to get that value after I press the Chrome extension with the blue N icon. Is this not possible?

Which gives error:

The code only works perfectly for all loaded pages but just not when the page is in an error state as in the above screenshot. Here's what I have:
manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Navigate to Stack Exchange Edit Profile",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Chrome extension that when clicked goes to Edit Profile",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon.png",
      "48": "icon.png",
      "128": "icon.png"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}

background.js:
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    if (tab.url) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            func: (url) => {
                alert('Current URL: ' + url);
            },
            args: [tab.url]
        });
    } else {
        alert('No URL available.');
    }
});

My end goal is to simply parse out the User ID from the address bar and then navigate to the URL https://<community>/users/edit/<User-ID>. I want it to work no matter where I am, as long as there is a User ID in the address bar. But that's all straightforward. For now, I would just like to get the alert to work even in an error state. That is my only question.
